# How to view the internal signals of module in ModelSim using the testbench?

Tags: vhdl, quartus, modelsim

I have looked over this tutorial ([Tutorial - Using Modelsim for Simulation, for Beginners.](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tutorials/tutorial-modelsim-simulation-walkthrough.html)
) how to add waves and write test benches for VHDL module

I looked over some answers as well like this one to find out but I could not use it.

[Quartus, Modelsim, VHDL - Viewing Internal Signals](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333034/quartus-modelsim-vhdl-viewing-internal-signals)

Now, if I want to add some internal signals and view them, how can I do since I am using the vhdl code as components in the testbench?

and to clarify it well, here is the code of the module:

```
 library ieee;
 use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

 entity and_gate is
 port (
 input_1    : in  std_logic;
  input_2    : in  std_logic;
 and_result : out std_logic
 );
 end and_gate;

 architecture rtl of and_gate is
 signal and_gate : std_logic; 
 signal not_and  : std_logic;
 begin
 and_gate   <= input_1 or input_2;
 and_result <= and_gate;   
 not_and    <= not and_gate;
 end rtl;
```

and here is the code of testbench
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

```
 entity and_gate_tb is
 end and_gate_tb;

 architecture behave of and_gate_tb is
 signal r_SIG1   : std_logic := '0';
 signal r_SIG2   : std_logic := '0';
 signal w_RESULT : std_logic;

 component and_gate is
 port (
  input_1    : in  std_logic;
  input_2    : in  std_logic;
  and_result : out std_logic);
 end component and_gate;

 begin

 and_gate_INST : and_gate
 port map (
  input_1    => r_SIG1,
  input_2    => r_SIG2,
  and_result => w_RESULT
  );

process is
begin
r_SIG1 <= '0';
r_SIG2 <= '0';
wait for 10 ns;
r_SIG1 <= '0';
r_SIG2 <= '1';
wait for 10 ns;
r_SIG1 <= '1';
r_SIG2 <= '0';
wait for 10 ns;
r_SIG1 <= '1';
r_SIG2 <= '1';
wait for 10 ns;    
end process;
 
end behave;
```

and here are my signals are all went to red eventhou I added their waves:
[image]

Comment: What exactly you didn't understand from [Quartus, Modelsim, VHDL - Viewing Internal Signals](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333034/quartus-modelsim-vhdl-viewing-internal-signals) ? It clearly shows how to add internal signals.

Comment: I updated my question. I did not understand how to add waves from vhdl code even though I added them as you see in the updated question

Comment: @Yaakov I wasn't able to reproduce your problem. The simulation gives me proper results and shows all internal signals. I had to complete the code of the testbench though: add libraries, entity and architecture declarations. I am not sure what the problem may be. Btw, you have a funny name for OR logic.

Comment: The code was mainly made for AND logic and I wanted just to check if I change the code,the waveform changes too.
What can go wrong in my testbench code then?

Comment: @Yaakov I have posted an answer, hope it helps. Let me know, if you need to see my testbench code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance, that you didn't compile all the updates in your code.

Here is how it should look:

[image: Modelsim screenshot]

Basically, you can add any signal in your project to a waveform to simulate. After creating `Simulation Configuration` you double click on it in a `Project` tab, which should get you to the `sim` tab. You will see the hierarchy of your project there. By clicking on the name of the entity under test, you will be able to see its internal signals in the `Objects` tab. Then you just right click the desired signals and choose `Add Wave`.

Comment: Perfect It is showing now the behaviour of internal signal.  a side question, in my modelSim window I do not have the same view as you where I can see the project tab, how can I bring it back?

Comment: I'm glad, that it helped. There is a `View` menu, where you can select `Project` by clicking or pressing `x`.

Comment: Would you mind adding / including the test-bench code to your answer? It could be rather helpful, I think.

Comment: @Henke Sure. Any working example is always useful, I guess.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure when I will have the time to look into the details, but very much appreciated that you added the code! 

Comment: @Henke Actually, I used the testbench code listed in the question. So I've deleted it from my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's your answer - you decide. No big deal. (And your test-bench is still accessible anyway.) Thanks, cheers! :-)